# Sage ACT for Web Custom Contact Tab - How to make it respond to switching contacts

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom plugin on the Sage ACT CRM for Web and when I switch contacts when the plugin is in view it does not switch the current contact on the plugin page.

If I switch tabs and go back then it switches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include this snippet of javascript in your aspx page.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
  function RefreshTabList()
  {
     location.reload(true);
  }
</script>
```

You can find reference to this on the [ACT Developer Community Forum](http://community.act.com/t5/Sage-ACT-Developer-s-Forum/ACT-for-Web-Custom-Contact-Tab-Not-Switching-when-you-move/m-p/207178/highlight/true#M5732):

Additionally, [I have discovered](http://community.act.com/t5/Sage-ACT-Developer-s-Forum/ACT-for-Web-Custom-Contact-Tab-Not-Switching-when-you-move/m-p/207178#M5732) that if you put a space in the plugin name this will stop working (at least as recently as ACT 2011).